# How to extract the first time a non-zero number occurs in dataframe n R?

Tags: r, dataframe

In an experiment, I'm trying to find the time to first birth. There are four animals as given by id and rep (A1, A2, B1, B2), their age and babies. For each id and rep, I want to only retain the rows where babies were first born

```
id <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
rep <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
age <- c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4)
babies <- c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1)

df <- data.frame(id,rep,age,babies)
```

So in here, the final dataframe should look like this

```
id <- c("A","A","B","B")
rep <- c(1,2,1,2)
age <- c(2,1,3,3)
babies <- c(1,1,1,1)

df <- data.frame(id,rep,age,babies)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(id, rep) %>% 
   slice_max(babies, n = 1, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
    ungroup
```

---

```
df %>%
   group_by(id, rep) %>% 
   filter(row_number() == which(babies > 0)[1]) %>% 
   ungroup
```

Comment: I wasn't clear in the text, the no of babies can also be greater than 1. So I'm not sure if the slice_max would hold?

Comment: @Biotechgeek I guess that is the reason I showed a `filter` approach as I was not sure whether your data have only binary or not

Answer (score 3):

You only need to `group_by` and `filter`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id, rep) %>% 
  filter(babies > 0) %>% 
  filter(age == min(age)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one with `arrange`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id, rep) %>% 
  arrange(-babies, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

```
  id      rep   age babies
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A         1     2      1
2 A         2     1      1
3 B         1     3      1
4 B         2     3      1
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative

```
df |> 
  group_by(id,rep) |> 
  slice(which(c(0, diff(babies)) == 1)) |> 
  ungroup()
```

This accounts for an individual having more babies as they age